# HTML file upload doesnt include file contents and cannot be recieved on golang webserver

Tags: html, go

**HTML FILE**

```
            <form class="form_container" id="Create-Form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                Create an account
                <input id="username"    type="text"     style="top:35%;" class="input-type1" placeholder="Username"/>
                <input id="password"    type="password" style="top:50%;" class="input-type1" placeholder="Password"/>
                <input id="password2"   type="password" style="top:65%;" class="input-type1" placeholder="Re-enter password"/>
                <input id="profile-pic" type="file"     style="top:75%;width: auto;" class="input-generic" name="file"/>
            </form>
```

**REQUEST DATA (unparsed)**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryeA1KWu6oBJDGu6vJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

NewUser
------WebKitFormBoundaryeA1KWu6oBJDGu6vJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

123
------WebKitFormBoundaryeA1KWu6oBJDGu6vJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password2"

123
------WebKitFormBoundaryeA1KWu6oBJDGu6vJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile-pic"

C:\fakepath\pic.jpg
------WebKitFormBoundaryeA1KWu6oBJDGu6vJ--
```

**GOLANG **

```
Request.ParseMultipartForm(Request.ContentLength)
ProfilePic, ProfilePicHeader, err := Request.FormFile("profile-pic")
```

From the form , whenever I send it the golang file keeps throwing errors due to there being "no such file". I'm really not sure as to what is going wrong here since im doing everything i could find on the internet to fix the issue so hopefully someone can offer me a direct solution to get this working. Thanks to anyone who can help out!

Comment: The unparsed request data and the provided HTML do not fit together. With `<input type=file`  the request data should contain the content of the file and not just the file name as shown. Please check what your HTML really is - or in case you don't use a browser to create the request then check the code for creating the request.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steffen Ullirch to responding, after him telling me that they didnt match i realised it wasnt actually the form sending but a piece of (poorly written) JS code that was interfering with the form post. After removing the files the post worked and the file binaries were included in the post. Again thanks for the help, wouldn't have realised that without you pointing it out!

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you found solution

Comment: Better to just delete the question since it didn't include enough information to solve the problem in the first place.